# Using Zynq, how to use one of the available DMAs in the Embedded Linux running on A53s

Tags: embedded-linux, device-driver, dma, device-tree, zynq

I’m using a Zynq board with 4 A-53 arm cores that run an embedded Linux (Ubuntu). I need to use a DMA to do a data transfer. When the Linux comes up, I see the following messages that show some DMAs are available:

[image: terminal]

In the device tree, I found the following DMAs (here I show only 2 of them). As you can see, they have the same register address as listed in the above screenshot. (gdma0 -> 0xfd500000 and so on).

[image: terminal 2]

Now in my device driver, I want to allocate a channel from one of these DMAs, say gdma0. When I call the following function, it returns an error:

```
 struct dma_chan    *dmachan;
 dmachan = dma_request_slave_channel_reason(pdev->dev, "gdma0");
 if (IS_ERR(dmachan)){
      printk(KERN_ALERT "error in allocating dma channel!\n");
      return -1;
 }
```

Then I defined a channel from gdma0 (in the device tree) as shown in the following:

[image]

And tried to allocate a channel in my driver as follow:

```
 dmachan = dma_request_slave_channel_reason(pdev->dev, "gdma");
 if (IS_ERR(dmachan)){
      printk(KERN_ALERT "error in allocating dma channel!\n");
      return -1;
 }
```

However, still I cannot allocate a DMA channel and the function returns an error.

Then based on Sanchayan comment, I moved the channel definition from the parent DMA node file to another file where I define my driver in the device tree. This is how I did that:

```
/ {
    ngd-tunnel { // my driver 
        compatible = "NGD,ngd-tunnel-char.a";
    };
    dma_channel: dma-channel@FD500000 {
        compatible = "xlnx,xilinx-zynqmp-dma";
        dmas = <&gdma0 0>;
        dma-names = "gdma";
    };
};
```

However, I get an error when I compile the project which is:

ERROR (phandle_references): Reference to non-existent node or label "gdma0"

Originally, it was the reason that I defined the channel in the parent DMA node.

Comment: Without knowing details of board you are using, more or less universal method to solve such problems is: check what particular error code is returned, then check sources of dma_request_slave_channel_reason() for possible locations from where this error return could come. Then, add a printk to each of those locations, recompile, rerun and see which of error paths hits. If needed, repeat this procedure several times to go deeper into other routines. At some point you will get to exact location where error situation is detected, and that should provide you a hint on what exactly is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Nikita for your suggestion. It cold be a good start. I will trace the error to see where exactly it comes from.

Comment: Do not add your channel in the parent node. A DMA channel is used by an independent driver let's say SPI which would be a DMA client. GDMA is DMA engine. You should define "dmas" and "dma-names" there and not in the original parent DMA node. Your driver's device tree node is where the channel definition should be.

Comment: Hi Sanchayan. Thanks for your help. As you said, I defined my channel in another file where I define my driver in the device tree. This is how I did that: / { ngd-tunneling { /* my driver */ compatible = "NGD,ngd-tunneling-char.a"; }; dma_channel: dma-channel@FD500000 { compatible = "xlnx,xilinx-zynqmp-dma"; dmas = <&gdma0 0>; dma-names = "gdma"; }; }; However, I get an error when I compile the project which is: ERROR (phandle_references): Reference to non-existent node or label "gdma0" Originally, it was the reason that I defined my channel in the parent DMA node.

Comment: Can you add your edits to the question? It is difficult to read the code change without formatting in comments.

Comment: Sure! I just added it to the end of my question.

Comment: What was the resolution for Reference to non-existent node or label ?